# Can i add a virtual object to my model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
ID   | Parent | Name
-----------------------------------------
1    | 0      | a
2    | 0      | b
3    | 2      | c
```

---

```
 [Table("Cats")]
    public class CategoriesModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? Parent { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int IsDr { get; set; }
        public virtual Submenu HasSubmenu { get; set; }
        public virtual CategoriesModel ParentMdl { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CategoriesModel> ChildrenMdl { get; set; }
    }
// My virtual class
    public partial class Submenu
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Has { get; set; }
        public virtual CategoriesModel Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CategoriesModel> ChildrenMdl { get; set; }
    }
```

when a row have no childs ( means no row has *parent* just like any IDs )

example : **ID** no. *1* has no any child, so **Submenu.Has** should be *false* !!

i dont know how i can do this, and where to do !!
Submenu is not a part of my table, it's virtual

can do this?

Comment: What is `RequestModel`?

Comment: Sorry @MegaTron, CategoriesModel is right!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: i've corrected my Post question !! check it again ! @MegaTron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I inderstand correctly, then `Has` should return...

- `true` - if `ChildrenMdl` has 1 or more elements;
- `false` - if `ChildrenMdl` has no elements (or perhaps it is even null).

This can be achieved as follows:

```
using System.Linq;

public partial class Submenu
{
    // ...
    public bool Has
    {
        get { return ChildrenMdl != null && ChildrenMdl.Any(); }
    }
    // ...
}
```

There is no `set { ... }` for the property, it simply would not make sense.

Also I removed the `virtual` keyword. Use `virtual` only if you want to allow subclasses to override the implementation of the property. If used when not needed then it makes the code run slightly slower.

Comment: above code perfectly helps me, but i've found new method as below function: `public CategoriesModel() HasSubmenu = new CategoriesSubmenu(); HasSubmenu.Has.Equals(!(ChildrenMdl != null && ChildrenMdl.Any()));}`. a new problem ! your above solution returns **false** , how can i  invert to true !!?